# Stretching Background Image in IE 8 and Below

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I want to load an image via css that stretches to the entire screen. The css:

```
body {

    background: url(images/reelgoodguide2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

}
```

Which works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox and IE9.

There is a conditional in the html to include an additional css file if the browser is IE8 or IE7. This css contains:

```
body{

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/reelgoodguide2.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/reelgoodguide2.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

But instead of alphaimageloader stretching the image to the entire screen, the image remains centered and it and does not resize.

Note: when I open developer tools I can see that the css file is there. When I disable the filter property, nothing happens. Any tips to what Im doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OKAY... After a grueling bit of fiddling, this is what i figured out:

First:
 The filter path to an image is relative to the html document, not the css file. *FRUSTRATING*

Second:
  I got this to work by applying the filter to `html` instead of `body`.

I had read that the IE workaround were not to be applied to `html` but what I noticed was that there was (after I had cleared up the image path problem) a stretched bacground image but it was *behind* everything else.

Comment: Oh my god thankyou! I had been trying everything till i read this, I ow you one :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible with CSS alone. Search for supersized. You will find some JavaScript libs.

Comment: no, it is possible. See my fix above. SO just wont let me accept it yet.

Answer (score 0):

One more useful answer to solve IE8 background issue is:

Download [backgroundsize.min.htc](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill/downloads) and put it inside your project.

Now simply add these lines in your css:

```
.class_name{
    //your other properties
    background-size: cover;
    -ms-behavior: url(backgroundsize.min.htc);
}
```

**NOTE: use the `url` according to your project setup.**

Enjoy this simple solution. **:)**